# Convert 24 V signal to 5 V with galvanic isolation

Tags: amplifier, sensor, dc, ttl, signal-conversion

I need to make an acquisition card signal (24 V) conversion to TTL signals (5 V) usable by intelligent cards with galvanic isolation.

Comment: This site isn't for questions like: "I want to build *this* but don't know how. How do I do it?" The "stupid" answer would be: **study and become a circuit designer, then design it**. Or you could search for an existing design and use that.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be either use a single optocoupler per signal, or optionally a optocoupler with multiple devices in a single package (e.g. DIP-16 with 4 optos)

Here you can see a schematic how it could be done:

[image: photo of optoisolation board and schematic]

<sub>Image source: [Amazon - Icstation 24V to 5V 8 Channel Optocoupler Isolation Board](https://www.amazon.sg/24V-Optocoupler-Voltage-Level-Converter/dp/B06XKSFGXX)</sub>

Optionally a Schmitt trigger can be used on the 5 V.

Comment: Hi, I found a source for the image you included (it seems to be available on several websites), so in order for your answer to meet [this site rule](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) I added that webpage link for you. If you got the image from a different webpage, please edit the answer and update the link & link text. Thanks :-)